# Values should be selected in dropdown once my page is loaded in angularJS (NgRoute)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using single page angular application. I have defined the static array in my typescript file. I want to bind my value from my Address array to the dropdown(select control). My ts file is as follows.

```
 let mainAngularModule = angular.module("mm", ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

    mainAngularModule.config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
    function routeConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/UserDefinedElement', {
                templateUrl: 'LinkType.html',
                controller: 'linktController as LTController'
            })
       .when('/PersonalPreferences', {
            templateUrl: 'PersonalPreference.html',
            controller: 'personalpreferencesController as PPController'
        })
}
```

and i have defined the class in same ts file which is as follows

```
class LinkTypeController {
    constructor() {

        $scope.items = [
            { Name: "LinkType1", Address: "NC"},
            { Name: "LinkType2", Address: "NY"}
        ];    

       this.AddressData= [
        { ID: 1, description: "NY" },
        { ID: 2, description: "NC" },
        { ID: 3, description: "SC" },
    ];       

    }
}

mainAngularModule.controller("linktController", LinkTypeController);
```

my Linktype HTML code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
        <div class="demo-md-panel-content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr  ng-repeat="x in items">
                        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                        <td>
          <md-select ng-model="selectedAddress" ng-model-options="{trackBy:'$value.ID'}">
                            <md-option ng-value="address" ng-repeat="address in LTController.AddressData track by $index">{{ address.description }}</md-option>
                        </md-select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when my page is loaded i want values from my address arrays to be selected in dropdown. Is something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-select ng-model="x.Address">
    <md-option ng-value="address.description" ng-repeat="address in LTController.AddressData track by $index">{{ address.description }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

1. Your `ng-model` needs to be bound to `x.Address` which is where the data comes from.
2. `ng-model-options - trackBy` needs to be removed because we are doing shallow comparison on string only.
3. `ng-value` on option needs to be `address.description` because this is the field to be matched against `x.Address`.

---

I've included a simple example. I'm not familiar with typescript so I've written using vanilla JS.

```js
angular.module('test', ['ngMaterial']).controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { Name: "LinkType1", Address: "NC"},
    { Name: "LinkType2", Address: "NY"}
  ];    

  $scope.AddressData = [
    { ID: 1, description: "NY" },
    { ID: 2, description: "NC" },
    { ID: 3, description: "SC" },
  ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='TestController'>
  <div ng-repeat='x in items'>
    <div>Name: {{x.Name}}</div>
    <div>
      <md-select ng-model='x.Address' aria-label='address'>
        <md-option ng-value='address.description' ng-repeat='address in AddressData'>{{address.description}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Values are being assigned to dropdown but its taking wrong values..taking last value from the array (Address as SC) for both rows.

Comment: @Bob please refer to example